# Unable to create instance to Cropperjs using react-cropper

Tags: reactjs, crop, cropperjs

I studied the [react-cropper](/questions/tagged/react-cropper) documentation on Github and tried to apply it.

The problem is - I am unable to initialize the cropper instance. As per the documentation we have to use onInitialized method. I did that, but I am unable to fire it.

When should I assume it should be fired - When a component is mounted or when I add image to it? Documentation is super blurry. Below is my code. It seems like `onCropperInit` function was never fired.

```
import React from 'react';
import Cropper from 'react-cropper';

export default class Demo extends React.Component{
    
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            image: "#"
        }
        this._crop = this._crop.bind(this);
        this.onCropperInit = this.onCropperInit.bind(this);
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
    }
    
    
 onChange(e) {
     
        e.preventDefault();
        let files;
    
            files = e.target.files;
        const reader = new FileReader();
  
        reader.onload = () => {
            this.setState({
            image: reader.result
            })
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
    };
    _crop(){
  
    }


onCropperInit(cropper){
console.log("cropper")
    this.cropper = cropper;
}

render(){
    return (
        <div>
         <input type="file" onChange={this.onChange} />
    
        <Cropper src={this.state.image} style={{height:"100vh",width: "90vw"}} aspectRatio={1067/600} guides={true} crop={this._crop} onInitialized={this.onCropperInit} dragMode="move"/>
    </div>
            )
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right. The github documentation says to use `onInitialized`, but it doesn't seem to work.

At least for now you can use a `ref` to get the cropper instance like this:

```
const cropper = React.createRef(null);

class Demo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._crop.bind(this);
  }

  _crop() {
    console.warn(cropper.current.cropper.getCroppedCanvas());
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Cropper
        src="http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/images/picture.jpg"
        style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}
        initialAspectRatio={16 / 9}
        guides={false}
        crop={this._crop}
        ref={cropper}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that certainly works. I am using react-cropper 1.3.0 and onInitialized function is for >2.0.0 version which is a beta version. Now while this is solved, I faced another problem - in the created reference I cannot seem to find this method `getCroppedCanvas()`. Is this a known issue as well? or I'll just post another question.

Comment: Also, why after doing this, `this.refs` is empty. As per the documentation we should use `this.refs.cropper.getCroppedCanvas().getDataURL()` but its empty instead cropper.current.cropper works

Comment: You should be able to execute `getCroppedCanvas`. You can find it in under `__proto__` if you log the cropper.

Comment: The `this.refs` syntax is legacy syntax https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs. So I'm guessing it doesn't work anymore for the react version you're using..

Comment: Thanks. I can see it under `_proto_. It as actually getDataURL() which says is not a function.